# Bot replying multiple times when triggered by reaction

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Right now I am making a discord bot (in version 12 of discord.js).

It works like this:

- Someone sends and insult
- If the insult is included in a list (stored in `insultes.json`) the bot send a message and adds a reaction
- If we add the same reaction the bot sends another message

The problem I'm facing is that if I keep adding the reaction the bot keeps replying 2, 3, 4 times and so on: every time (n) I check the reaction it replies with n+1 messages.

This is the code:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
  const insulte = require('./insultes.json');

  for (let p = 0; p < insulte.length; p++) {
    // Check if the insult is in the list and make sure it's not from the bot itself
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(insulte[p]) && message.author.id !== "711337757435363468") {
      message.channel.send("First message").then(messageReaction => {
        messageReaction.react("➡️");
      });

      bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === "➡️" && user.id !== "711337757435363468") {
          message.channel.send("Additional message");
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the fact that you're using `bot.on('messageReactionAdd', ...`: that means that every time you run that part of the code the code will add another listener that adds up to the ones that you used before.

Also, that code will trigger when a reaction to any message is added, not just the one you sent.

From your question, I don't understand if the bot is supposed to reply with one message every time you hit the reaction on that message, or just do it once and then ignore the message. I'll assume it's the latter.

Here's my take on this:

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
  const insults = require('./insultes.json')

  if (insults.some(i => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(i)) && message.author.id !== "711337757435363468") {
    message.channel.send("First message").then(myMsg=> {
      myMsg.react("➡️");

      let reactionFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '➡️' && user.id !== "711337757435363468"
      myMsg.awaitReactions(reactionFilter, { max: 1 }).then(() => {
        myMsg.channel.send('Additional message')
      })
    });
  }
})
```

As you can see, I'm using [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check whether any insult is in the message, instead of a `for` loop. I'm using [`Message.awaitReactions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions) to fetch the first reaction and respond to that: after that, the bot will just ignore any other reaction on that message, but will still work on others.

Feel free to let me know if something is not clear or doesn't work :)

Comment: That's working at 100% Thanks a lot for helping me ! :D

Comment: @Drakeu0909 I'm happy to hear that! In Stack Overflow when an answer solves your problem you can accept it by clicking the tick on the left: this way your question will be marked as answered and so everybody will know that they don't need to post another answer ;)

Comment: Okay, but I have another question, I want that the message be send when the reaction get triggered, but only by the message author (the one who send the insult)

Comment: don't worry I find